# Would an inductor work differently under a different dielectric environment?

Tags: inductor, insulation, dielectric

I am talking about these common rounded inductors with a metal core that you would find on PCBs.
[image]

Would the operation be different in, say, mineral oil vs. air? These are two different dielectric substance that surround the componenet.

I think it wouldn't make a difference, as the wire is already insulated with some varnish, so external properties don't matter much as long as it's dielectric?

Answer (score 0):

Not generally.

The dielectric affects the electric field (from voltage), but the inductor's properties depend on the magnetic susceptibility of the materials. These are quite different and not related.

The only time there would be an effect is if transmission line effects affected the properties of the inductor. This is not the case in components intended for use as actual inductors.

Comment: I can imagine that a gapped inductor might change somewhat if oil got into the gap, I’ve no idea by how much though.

Comment: @Frog from what you said, some transformers might be affected if I change the dielectric if they used to have an air gap?

Comment: @jp314 on a separate note, for those cylindrical capacitors, they ought to be tightly sealed right? otherwise a different dielectric getting in would alter the behavior

Comment: @HYQ most capacitors are sealed, the only exceptions I can think of are air-gapped rotary adjustable capacitors

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal toroidal inductor all field lines lie within the magnetic material. Adding a dielectric would be equivalent to making the wire insulation thicker.
Overall, no change

Comment: What about interwinding capacitance increase? It would alter the self-resonant frequency.

Comment: Probably, but I was talking about an ideal inductor where we can ignore such things. If we are not ignoring the real world, then temperature also has an effect on just about everything. Then we would have to take into account any polar molecular properties etc